# Disable ivy-mode in a specific buffer

Tags: ivy

Evaluating `(ivy-mode 0)` in a buffer kills ivy across all the other buffers, too. How to stop ivy in a specific buffer only (I don't need it in ERC, where i want `TAB` to give me a list of all the people in the channel, not just ten of them).

Comment: Just to be clear - Ivy doesn't truncate the collection of candidates to a size of ten; it displays some arbitrary number of candidates at a time and allows you to navigate through and further narrow the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to stop ivy in a specific buffer only

At the time of writing, Ivy is a [global minor mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html) which modifies the variables `completing-read-function` and `completion-in-region-function`, and remaps a couple of global buffer switching key bindings.

This means that it is not currently designed to be en/disabled on a per-buffer basis. The closest you can come to achieving this is by reverting the aforementioned variables to their original values [buffer-locally](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Locals.html). For example:

```el
(defun my-default-completion ()
  "Locally revert completion variables to their default values."
  (setq-local completing-read-function #'completing-read-default)
  (setq-local completion-in-region-function #'completion--in-region))

(add-hook 'some-mode-hook #'my-default-completion)
```

This will not, of course, affect the globally remapped key bindings.

If you're lucky and know where to look, you can sometimes achieve more granular control of how calls to `completing-read` are performed under `ivy-mode` by customising `ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist`.

I don't think it would be completely unreasonable to file a feature request on the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues) for a non-global version of `ivy-mode`.

Comment: If I was to remap most of Ivy's counsel functionality to certain keys, I wouldn't really need to `(ivy-mode 1)` at all, would I? What do I need the minor mode for?